# Test an API Controller Symfony 4 || that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity:

Tags: entity-framework, symfony

First of all, i'm worry about my english. I'm really sorry if you don't understand.

I work on a API Project to improve my skills in React and Symfony.

So I work with a Test Driven Developpement. My problem is that i use some Fixture to test.

My first route to get result is ok. But when i want POST , it's an other thing because i got 2 ManyTo Relation.

I use Liip\TestFixturesBundle\ for my fixtures;

This is my test function:

```
    public function testAPIProjectPOST(){
        $client = static::createClient();
        $fixtures = $this->loadFixtureFiles([
            __DIR__ . '/../Fixtures/DataBaseFixture.yaml'
        ]);
        $parameters = [
            'name' => "ProjectTestAPI",
            'description' => "First Project in POST",
            'difficulty' => 4,
            'skills' => [1],
            'owner' => 1
        ];
        $client->request('POST','/api/project',[],[],['CONTENT_TYPE'=>'application/json'],json_encode($parameters));
        $content = $client->getResponse();
        $this->assertResponseStatusCodeSame(Response::HTTP_CREATED);

    }
```

I got these error :

```
A new entity was found through the relationship 'App\Entity\Project#skills' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: App\Entity\Skill@00000000726fccc80000000059a1c5e2. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={&quot;persist&quot;}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'App\Entity\Skill#__toString()' to get a clue.
 * A new entity was found through the relationship 'App\Entity\Project#owner' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: App\Entity\User@00000000726fcd310000000059a1c5e2. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={&quot;persist&quot;}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'App\Entity\User#__toString()' to get a clue. (500 Internal Server Error) -->
```

Thank you a lot for your answers !

UPDATE : More code

Datafixture.yaml :

```
App\Entity\User:
  user{1..10}:
    username: user<current()>
    email: user<current()>\@domain.fr
    password: '0000'

App\Entity\Skill:
  skill{1..3}:
    name: skill<current()>

App\Entity\Project:
  project{1..10}:
    name: project<current()>
    description: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean egestas id eros sit amet maximus. Donec fringilla diam et elementum ultricies.
    owner: '@user<current()>'
    difficulty: <numberBetween(1,5)>
    skills: ['@skill<numberBetween(1,3)>']
```

PageController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Project;
use App\Repository\ProjectRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\NotEncodableValueException;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

class ApiProjectController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/api/project", name="api_project", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function index(ProjectRepository $projectRepository)
    {
        return $this->json($projectRepository->findAll(),200,[],['groups'=>'project:read']);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/api/project", name="api_project_store", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function store(Request $request,SerializerInterface $serializer,EntityManagerInterface $em,ValidatorInterface $validator){
        $json = $request->getContent();
        try{
            $post = $serializer->deserialize($json, Project::class,'json');

            $errors = $validator->validate($post);

            if (count($errors)>0){
                return $this->json($errors,400);
            }

            $em->persist($post);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->json($post,201,[],['groups'=>'read']);
        }
        catch(NotEncodableValueException $e){
            return $this->json([
                'status'=>400,
                'message'=> $e->getMessage()
            ],400);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, provide more code. Looks like you're working with entity manager inside your controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution :

I add in my post controller, UserRepository and SkillRepository.

```
    public function store(Request $request,SerializerInterface $serializer,EntityManagerInterface $em,ValidatorInterface $validator,UserRepository $userRepository,SkillRepository $skillRepository){
    $json = $request->getContent();
    try{
        $project = $serializer->deserialize($json, Project::class,'json');
        $project->setOwner($userRepository->find(json_decode($json)->owner));
        $project->initializeSkills();
        foreach(json_decode($json)->skills as $idSkill){
            $project->addSkill($skillRepository->find($idSkill));
        }
        $errors = $validator->validate($project);

        if (count($errors)>0){
            return $this->json($errors,400);
        }

        $em->persist($project);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->json($project,201,[],['groups'=>'project:read']);
    }
    catch(NotEncodableValueException $e){
        return $this->json([
            'status'=>400,
            'message'=> $e->getMessage()
        ],400);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess skills is a OneToMany Relation and owner a ManyToOne to the resource you're trying to POST. When Doctrine tries to persist the Ressource it checks whether these Subressources exist. They don't. And since cascade persist isnt set on those fields, Doctrine doesnt know what to do.

You can either set cascade persist. 
Or you can first try to get those Ressources and if you dont get them, create them. 
When you're sure your Subressources exist, you can post your Ressource.

Comment: But my subressource should exist with loadFixtures,When i got my ressource with my GET route i got 10 projects with 10 differents users and 3 different skills.

Answer (score 0):

I search again, but i don't know why my fixtures is'nt considered :/ If someone had a response ?